# Maven not showing libraries

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, dependencies

When I right click on my project and go to maven > add depedency it says "Artifact id cannot be empty". Basically i can't search for anything if i write "hibernate" it only shows 3 options (none including hibernate validator) yet if I write at group id: org.hibernate, artifact-id: hibernate-validator and version: 4.2.0.Final it knows what to download (i can find them under Libraries > Maven Dependencies.

Anyone knows why this happens?Thank you. I forgot to mention i'm a beginner regarding Java EE and Maven etc.

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing ? You are not able to add hiberate ??

Comment: Yes I am able I just can't see the Search Results. If I type the required group Id, Artifact Id and Version it works without problem, I just can't use Maven to search for dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is true , it will always display all the results on the basis of search criteria. For more please see the attached image.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: for some reason the same doesn't happen to me.

Comment: actually it is very strange , if it is not working for you. :( - Thanks